# Name error while trying to generate some report

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def state_from_record(state_name):
    state_split = state_name.split(",")
    return state_split

def cases_from_record(covid_cases):
    covid_split = covid_cases.split(",")
    return covid_split

def deaths_from_record(covid_deaths):
    death_split = covid_deaths.split(",")
    return death_split

result1 = state_from_record(result[0])
print(result1)
```

This is the second part of the code which continues on:

```
   import random
    def state_report(state, data_list):
        if state_split is random:
            states = choice(state_split)
            for s in states:
                if states == state_split:
                    return states + "\n" + "Total Confirmed Cases: " + covid_split + "Total Deaths: " + death_split
                else:
                    return "No record found for " + states
    
    result2 = state_report(states, state_split)
    print(result2)
```

I am trying to use a previous code and it keeps on coming as a name error saying that "states" doesn't exist.

here is my output:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-8fee8f642c90> in <module>()
     10                 return "No record found for " + states
     11 
---> 12 result2 = state_report(states, state_split)
     13 print(result2)

NameError: name 'states' is not defined
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the `state` parameter? It's never used. It seems like you should just change the function to `def state_report(data_list):`, then call it as `state_report(state_split)`. You're getting the error because `states` doesn't exist in that scope.

Comment: `states` is a local variable in the function, you can't access it outside the function.

Comment: What do you expect `if state_split is random:` to do? Where do you set `state_split` before calling `state_report()`?

Answer (score 0):

What you are bumping into is a programming concept called the [scope](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/scope-of-variables-python)

Imagine these two functions:

```python
def first_func():

    foo = "abc"
    print(foo)

def second_func():

    print(foo)

second_func()
```

Running this code will raise `NameError`, because variable `foo` is out of the *scope* of the `second_func`, since it is defined within the boundaries of the `first_func`.

If you move the variable `foo` out of the first function, like so:

```python
foo = "abc"

def first_func():

    print(foo)

def second_func():

    print(foo)

second_func()
```

Both functions will run fine. Because variable `foo` is now defined in a broader scope and accessible from within both functions.